# How can I expand variables in text strings?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script where I read in a line from a configuration file that contains a variable name. When I read the line into a variable the variable name that needs to be replaced with the given value is not put in. I am using [Config::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aTiny) to access my configuration file. Example:

#### configuration file

```
thing=I want to $this
```

#### script

```
$this = "run";
my $thing = $Config->{thing};
print $thing;
```

---

`print $thing` comes out as `I want to $this`. I want it to come out as `I want to run`.

Comment: Got some code to show? It will help you get good answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so you're wanting Perl to evaluate your string as opposed to print it.

This is actually covered in this Perl FAQ:
[How can I expand variables in text strings?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3f)

In short, you can use the following regular expression:

```
$string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg;
```

**BE CAREFUL:** Evaluating arbitrary strings from outside of your scripts is a major security risk. A good hacker can exploit this to execute arbitrary code on your server.

Brian's FAQ answer covers some of this.

Comment: Tip o' the hat to Brian D. Foy who wrote the reference FAQ and who is a regular contributor to SO on a wide range of matters.

Comment: I think you mean brian d foy ;-)

Comment: Erk... yeah... I Googlized and found that even the front of Learning Perl has 'brian d foy'... hope I haven't committed a major 'foy pas' (sorry...couldn't resist :oP )

Comment: It turns out if you also have ${var}, the above doesn't work. This pattern handled both cases: $string =~ s/(\$\w+|\${\w+})/$1/eeg;

Answer (score 3):

Use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
print eval $thing;
```

With package variables it's also possible to use [symbolic references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references):

```
$thing =~ s/\$(\w+)/$$1/;
```

Comment: +1, this regex solution with symbolic references is definately a much safer solution than string eval or a regex with an eval group