# How explicitly resolve variables in a perl string?

Tags: string, perl

In my perl script I want to have both versions of `$config` directory:

```
my $config='$home/client/config';
```

and

```
my $config_resolved="$home/client/config";
```

But I want to get `$config_resolved` from `$config`, i.e. something like this:

```
my $config_resolved=resolve_vars($config);
```

How can I do such thing in perl?

Comment: duplicates [How can I expand variables in text strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736844/how-can-i-expand-variables-in-text-strings)

Answer (score 5):

From the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html) (which every Perl programmer should read at least once):

> [How can I expand variables in text strings?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3f)
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can
>   use a templating system, such as Text::Template or Template Toolkit,
>   do that instead. You might even be able to get the job done with
>   `sprintf` or `printf`:
>
> ```
> my $string = sprintf 'Say hello to %s and %s', $foo, $bar;
> ```
>
> However, for the one-off simple case where I don't want to pull out a
>   full templating system, I'll use a string that has two Perl scalar
>   variables in it. In this example, I want to expand `$foo` and `$bar` to
>   their variable's values:
>
> ```
> my $foo = 'Fred';
> my $bar = 'Barney';
> $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
> ```
>
> One way I can do this involves the substitution operator and a double `/e` flag. The
>   first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and turns it into `$foo`. The
>   second `/e` starts with `$foo` and replaces it with its value. `$foo`,
>   then, turns into 'Fred', and that's finally what's left in the string:
>
> ```
> $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
> ```
>
> The `/e` will also silently ignore violations of strict, replacing undefined
>   variable names with the empty string. Since I'm using the `/e` flag
>   (twice even!), I have all of the same security problems I have with
>   eval in its string form. If there's something odd in `$foo`, perhaps
>   something like `@{[ system "rm -rf /" ]}`, then I could get myself in
>   trouble.
>
> To get around the security problem, I could also pull the
>   values from a hash instead of evaluating variable names. Using a
>   single `/e`, I can check the hash to ensure the value exists, and if it
>   doesn't, I can replace the missing value with a marker, in this case
>   `???` to signal that I missed something:
>
> ```
> my $string = 'This has $foo and $bar';
> my %Replacements = (
>     foo  => 'Fred',
>     );
> # $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/$Replacements{$1}/g;
>
> $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/
>             exists $Replacements{$1} ? $Replacements{$1} : '???'
>             /eg;
> print $string;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I use `eval` for this.
So, you must replace all scalars (their names) with their values.

```
$config = 'stringone';
$boo = '$config/any/string';
$boo =~ s/(\$\w+)/eval($1)/eg;
print $boo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using my to declare it as private variable, you might as well use a **/ee** modifier. This can find variables declared to be in local scope:

```
$boo =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is most tidily and safely done by the double-eval modifier on `s///`.

In the program below, the first `/e` evaluates the string `$1` to get `$home`, while the second evaluates `$home` to get the variable's value `HOME`.

```
use strict;

my $home = 'HOME';

my $config = '$home/client/config';

my $config_resolved = resolve_vars($config);

print $config_resolved, "\n";

sub resolve_vars {
  (my $str = shift) =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg;
  return $str;
}
```

**output**

```
HOME/client/config
```

Comment: Would the downvoter like to say what he thinks is wrong with this answer?